# A table transform

Tags: sql-server

I have a table transform question.  This is a reason-result question.

As an example, a group of kindergarden students will read a number of books.  When a student finishs reading his FIRST book, he should be given an apple as a gift.  He can never be given more than one apple.  However, in reality the result is not always as designed, and errors might occur. Apples might not be given, or given at the wrong time.

The following two tables are example data:

```
create table #Reason (Student VARCHAR(20), BookName VARCHAR(20), FinishTime DateTime)
INSERT INTO #Reason VALUES
     ('Student1', 'Book11', '2015-03-01 13:00:00')
    ,('Student1', 'Book12', '2015-03-02 10:00:00')
    ,('Student1', 'Book13', '2015-03-03 18:00:00')
    ,('Student2', 'Book21', '2015-03-01 16:00:00')
    ,('Student2', 'Book22', '2015-03-02 18:00:00')
    ,('Student2', 'Book23', '2015-03-03 18:00:00')
    ,('Student2', 'Book24', '2015-03-04 18:00:00')
    ,('Student3', 'Book31', '2015-03-01 6:00:00')
    ,('Student3', 'Book32', '2015-03-02 8:00:00')
    ,('Student3', 'Book33', '2015-03-03 9:00:00')
    ,('Student3', 'Book34', '2015-03-04 12:00:00')
-----------------------------------------------------
create table #Result (Student VARCHAR(20), GiftName VARCHAR(20), GiftTime DateTime)
INSERT INTO #Result VALUES 
     ('Student1', 'Apple', '2015-03-01 13:01:00')
    ,('Student2', 'Apple', '2015-03-01 18:01:00') 
    ,('Student2', 'Apple', '2015-03-03 15:01:00') 
    ,('Student2', 'Apple', '2015-03-04 15:08:00')
    ,('Student2', 'Apple', '2015-03-04 15:09:00')
    ,('Student3', 'Apple', '2015-02-28 10:01:00')
    ,('Student4', 'Apple', '2015-04-28 10:01:00')
```

---

The required output table should be (A correct column is added to indicate whether the apple is given at the right time):

```
('Yes','Student1', 'Book11', '2015-03-01 13:00:00',  'Apple', '2015-03-01 13:01:00')
('Yes' ,'Student1', 'Book12', '2015-03-02 10:00:00',   NULL  , NULL                 )
('Yes' ,'Student1', 'Book13', '2015-03-03 18:00:00',   NULL  , NULL                 )
('Yes','Student2', 'Book21', '2015-03-01 16:00:00',  'Apple', '2015-03-01 18:01:00')
('No ','Student2', 'Book22', '2015-03-02 18:00:00',  'Apple', '2015-03-03 15:01:00')
('No ','Student2', 'Book23', '2015-03-03 18:00:00',  'Apple', '2015-03-04 15:08:00')
('No ','Student2', 'Book23', '2015-03-03 18:00:00',  'Apple', '2015-03-04 15:09:00')
('Yes' ,'Student2', 'Book24', '2015-03-04 18:00:00',   NULL  , NULL                 )
('No ','Student3', 'Book31', '2015-03-01 06:00:00',   NULL  , NULL                 )
('No ','Student3', NULL    , NULL                 ,  'Apple', '2015-02-28 10:01:00')
('Yes' ,'Student3', 'Book32', '2015-03-02 8:00:00' ,   NULL  , NULL                 )
('Yes' ,'Student3', 'Book33', '2015-03-03 9:00:00' ,   NULL  , NULL                 )
('Yes' ,'Student3', 'Book34', '2015-03-04 12:00:00',   NULL  , NULL                 )    
('No ','Student4', NULL    , NULL                 ,  'Apple', '2015-04-28 10:01:00')
```

Comment: how much difference in the time between a student reads a book and an apple is given is acceptable for it to be a match? can you also provide what you have tried so far

Comment: Any time.  If the gift time is after the finished reading time of the first book and before the  finished reading time of the second book, then it is considered as the right time.

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this for. From SQL Server 2012 there are a couple of windowing functions available that might be useful.

Comment: can you detail why there is a 'No' for 'Student2', 'Book22'. from the data it looks that the order for Student 2 and book 22 is correct

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: ughai,  The rule is a student can only be given one apple.  The second apple will be considered as wrong.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/60f4d/4)

For SQL Server 2008

```
;WITH Reason as
(
Select Student,BookName,FinishTime,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY student ORDER BY FinishTime) BookNo,
  (SELECT MIN(FinishTime) FROM #Reason R2 WHERE R2.Student = R1.Student AND R2.FinishTime > R1.FinishTime) Next_Finish
FROM #Reason R1
),
Reason_WithGift as
(
SELECT *
FROM Reason Rn
),
Results as
(
SELECT Student,GiftName,GiftTime,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY student ORDER BY GiftTime) GiftNo
FROM #Result
)
SELECT CASE WHEN ((BookNo = 1 AND GiftNo = 1) OR(BookNo <> 1 AND GiftNo IS NULL)) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END,ISNULL(Rn.Student,Rt.Student) Student,Rn.BookName,Rn.FinishTime,Rt.GiftName,Rt.GiftTime
FROM Reason_WithGift Rn
FULL OUTER JOIN Results Rt
    ON Rt.Student = Rn.Student 
        AND Rt.GiftTime BETWEEN Rn.FinishTime 
        AND ISNULL(Next_Finish,'2999/12/31')
ORDER BY ISNULL(Rn.Student,Rt.Student),Rn.BookName
```

For SQL Server 2012 and above

```
;WITH Reason as
(
Select Student,BookName,FinishTime,LEAD(FinishTime)OVER(partition by student order by FinishTime) Next_Finish,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY student ORDER BY FinishTime) BookNo
FROM #Reason
),
Reason_WithGift as
(
SELECT *
FROM Reason Rn
),
Results as
(
SELECT Student,GiftName,GiftTime,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY student ORDER BY GiftTime) GiftNo
FROM #Result
)
SELECT IIF((BookNo = 1 AND GiftNo = 1) OR(BookNo <> 1 AND GiftNo IS NULL),'Yes','No'),ISNULL(Rn.Student,Rt.Student) Student,Rn.BookName,Rn.FinishTime,Rt.GiftName,Rt.GiftTime
FROM Reason_WithGift Rn
FULL OUTER JOIN Results Rt
    ON Rt.Student = Rn.Student 
        AND Rt.GiftTime BETWEEN Rn.FinishTime 
        AND ISNULL(Next_Finish,'2999/12/31')
ORDER BY ISNULL(Rn.Student,Rt.Student),Rn.BookName
```

Comment: Thank you very much ughai.  Our SQL Server does not recognise LEAD() function and IIF.

Comment: Excellent ughai.  Great job!

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: How does [accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? for more information

Comment: ughai,  I added a data,('Student2', 'Apple', '2015-03-04 15:09:00') and the query  does not show it correctly.

Comment: The initial query only mapped a single gift to a book. updated the answer to incorporate multiple gifts mapped to a single book.

Answer (score 0):

With ughai's help, I modify the query, and it works.  Thanks ughaim again!

But I do not know how to post my change.

The change:

1. Get rid of the reason_withgift temp table
2. change the result temp table similar to Reason table
3. use the following to replace the time condition in the where clause

   AND Reason.FinishTime <= Result.GiftTime
   AND Reason.Next_FinishTime >= Result.GiftTime